# Dealing with overlaping week and year numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

A new year with new problems! I have several Excel based rapports that pull data from an Oracle table. However i noticed a problem related to year and weeks in Excel. Here is and example:

[image: Wrong result]

The formula i use now is `Week(A1;21)` for the week and `Year(A1)` for the year.

Is there a way that i can get the correct year for the whole week based on the date in excel (see week 1 of 2015 in the picture above)

The result i want is this:

[image: Correct result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
=YEAR(A1)+AND(WEEKNUM(A1;21)=1;MONTH(A1)=12)
```

Comment: I like the solution, strange i dident think of that. I was imagening a solution similar to formating year as IYYY in Oracle SQL, but i guess this works. Thank you :)